# Session variable does not change its value

Tags: php, linux, session, vps

I am using VPS, with kloxo panel, here is my phpinfo http://bit.ly/wAel9J

here is my code

```
if(isset($_SESSION["oldtime"])):

$oldtime = $_SESSION["oldtime"];

else:
    $oldtime =  time() - 10;

endif;

$sql = "select *  from chat_status where  c_session > $oldtime  ";

$res = mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0):

      $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

       $_SESSION["oldtime"] = $row['c_session'];

endif;
```

I have update session value from database, but session remains unset. no value comes in session variable

i suppose it is problem with my hosting. i have my own VPS. please advice me how can i overcome this issue

Comment: did you do `session_start()` before doing any of your session based activities?

Comment: Ugh, I'll never understand why people use the alternative syntax instead of curly braces in PHP...

Comment: @ThiefMaster: When ui designer's wrongly choose programming as their career :P they start looking for good Look & Feel in just everything they do, even in programming :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is anywhere before your inserted code here 
session_start(); ??

sorry, don't know how to write a comment on your question

Comment: actually it behaves very Odd on some places it echo $_SESSION['as']; variable as Array, and some places it does not change its value